# Is it possible set Named Range scope to worksheet by default?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible configure Excel (maybe a check box Option available), so that, when I create a named range using the "shortcut" in the formula bar, the scope is set by default to the active worksheet, instead of to the whole workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, it's not possible to change that default in Excel.

However, `Define Name` exists as a command in its own right. This means that one thing you can do is to add a custom ribbon button to go directly to the `Define Name` dialog.

[image]

This saves navigating to the Name Manager and drilling down within that to get to this dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Changing default setting of the SCOPE OF NAMED RANGE to specific worksheet is looking difficult.*

*A Name can be either global to a workbook or local to a worksheet. The standard method is create a Range name as a global names, but yes you can set the SCOPE OF NAMED RANGE to any specific worksheet.*

**Method 1:**

- While creating Named Range, you can pick a worksheet from the list, then Excel will restrict it's scope to the sheet only.

[image]

**Method 2:**

- You may use this VBA code to change the SCOPE of the NAMED RANGE.

  ```
   Sub ChangeScope()
     Application.Calculation = xlManual
      Names("MyName").Delete
       Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10").Name = 
        "Sheet1!MyName"
          Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    End Sub
  ```

**N.B.**

**1.** This single line can do it also.

```
Sheet1.Names.Add("Myname", Sheet1.Range("A1:A10"))
```

**2.** In this code you may adjust cell references
and NAME of the Range as you need.

**3.** Code `Change Scope` can be used as `Workbook Open event` (calling Macro) also.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Rajesh. Since both answers were good, I had to choose the first one posted.

Comment: Hey @sergiotrajano,, glad to help you now you may up vote also,, for details [Check this](https://superuser.com/tour) ,, keep asking ☺

Comment: I just upvoted, but since my reputation is less than 15, my upvote do not shows up to everyone, but is counted :)

Comment: @sergiotrajano,, it's okay no issue ☺